# RegisterClassHandler vs. AddHandler In WPF Custom Control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

When writing a WPF custom control, there is sometime the need to capture child elements events in order to implement some logic.

One alternative is to hook to events in `OnApplyTemplate` (and unhook in `OnTemplateChanged`).

Another alternative is to use `RegisterClassHandler` in a static constructor.

What are the pros and cons for each alternative?

Thanks.